# Fixing a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, path

I'm trying to write a program that uses recursive method find number of paths from start of two dimension array to the end . The steps should start from [0][0] till the end . Array is filled by int number between 0 to 99 .

For every number in the array can be two different steps forward : for example if [0][0] is 21 , next step could be [0+2][0+1] or [0+1][0+2] .
The method should return number of different paths to get to the final point .

Here is my code :

During the comilation a have overflow when the method gets [][] array

```
     public class two
        {
            int[][] _my=new int[0][0];
            public two ()
        {
        }
        static int count=0;
        public static int count;

ountPath(int[][] mat)
    {
        int nextX=0;
        int nextY=0;
        int current=mat[0][0];
        if (current<=9)
        {
            nextX=current;
            nextY=current;
            if (checkBorders(0,0,nextX,nextY,mat)==0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            nextX=(int)current/10;
            nextY=current%10;
            if (checkBorders(0,0,nextX,nextY,mat)==0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        countPath(mat,nextX,nextY);
        countPath(mat,nextY,nextX);
        return count;
    }

    public static int countPath(int[][] mat,int x,int y)
    {
        int current=mat[x][y];
        int nextX=0;
        int nextY=0;
        int terminate=0;
        if (current<=9)
        {
            nextX=current;
            nextY=current;
            if (checkBorders(x,y,nextX,nextY,mat)==0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            nextX=(int)current/10;
            nextY=current%10;
            if (checkBorders(x,y,nextX,nextY,mat)==0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        if (((mat.length-1)==nextY)&&((mat[0].length-1)==nextX))
        {
           terminate=1;
        }

        if (terminate==1)
            count++;
        else
        {
        countPath(mat,nextX,nextY);
        countPath(mat,nextY,nextX);
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int checkBorders(int x,int y,int x1,int y1,int[][] mat)
    {
        int maxX=mat[0].length;
        int maxY=mat.length;
        if ((x+x1)>maxX)
            return 0;
        else if ((y+y1)>maxY)
            return 0;
        else return 1;
    }

}
```

Please help me to fix the code.

Comment: How is it not working? is `count` a static variable? btw in java you can use `boolean`

Comment: If the code is self containing it might be helpful to not only say what the problem is, but to also post the complete code.

Comment: Yes , i use static count variable .

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one more array of bool where u will store which state have already been visited. Now you may come to following scenario:

You are in state A.
From state A you can go to states B and C.
From state B you can go to state A <- this will be infinite loop.

Also the memorization will increase calculation speed drastically.

Hope I helped you.